# My new window closed automatically, and it's not switching to main window getting no such window exception target window is closed in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Help me with no such window exception, target window is already closed.i have to switch to new popup window which closed automatically, again I have open new window, by clicking button in main window and I m not able to switch into the main window . What I have to do

I need to open second window. By clicking on button in main window